Display Pattern Names within Editor Pattern Selector
I am adding a pattern via the patterns folder. I have the title and slug set.
<?php
/**
 * Title: The Title I want to display
 * Slug: myTheme/pattern-name
 * Categories: myTheme
 * Block Types: core/navigation

 */

?>

I am using v3 of theme.json and have also registered the pattern there.
"patterns": [
  "myTheme/pattern-name"
]

The thing that's driving me crazy is that when a user goes to add a pattern in the editor it only shows the name on hover. Patterns created via the editor show their names right under the thumbnail. I am going to be creating a bunch of patterns and sometimes there will not be much visually to go on, as they might be something like just containers with classes. How do I get the name to display there to make it easier for the user to select the correct pattern?

Looking at the code for BlockPattern (that renders the block pattern selections), it seems only user-created patterns are shown the title, as you say. Seems like you may need to somehow "fake" the patterns as user patterns or fork the block editor to change this bit of code.
